# SQL Assign a variable in a SELECT and do a CASE with the variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way in doing something like this

declare a variable, assign a value to it in a select statement, then use it in a case  ?

Something like this

```
DECLARE @result BIGINT;

SELECT @result = (SELECT count(_t.Id) FROM T _t WHERE _t.T2Id = _t2.Id GROUP BY _t.T2Id)
CASE WHEN @result IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @result END AS ColNAme
FROM T2 _t2
```

The idea is that I would like to avoid doing the select count query twice.

```
CASE 
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(_t.Id) FROM T _t WHERE _t.T2Id = _t2.Id GROUP BY _t.T2Id) IS NULL THEN 0 
ELSE (SELECT COUNT(_t.Id) FROM T _t WHERE _t.T2Id = _t2.Id GROUP BY _t.T2Id) END AS ColNAme
```

I don't want to use functions.

The result set should contain the count of all T items that have a T2 reference by T2 Id

```
ID | Count
2  |   0
4  |   12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a variable defined in one `select` later in the script.  But you still use two `select` queries (note the following doesn't work so read the whole answer):

```
DECLARE @result BIGINT;

SELECT @result = (SELECT count(_t.Id) FROM T _t WHERE _t.T2Id = _t2.Id GROUP BY _t.T2Id);

SELECT (CASE WHEN @result IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @result END) AS ColNAme
FROM T2 _t2;
```

Notes:

- The first query will return an error because `_t2` is not defined.
- The second query should just use `COALESCE(@result, 0)`.
- `@result` will never be `NULL`, because `COUNT()` never returns a `NULL` value.  So the second query could really be just `select @result`.
- Returning the same value for every row in `T2` is strange.  I imagine your actually query is more interesting.
- There is no reason to use a variable, unless you need the value later in the script.

So, based on your desired results, I think you simply want a `left join` and `group by`:

```
select t2.id, count(t.id)
from t2 left join
     t 
     on t2.id = t.t2id
group by t2.id;
```